# UIButton not working in tableview cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uibutton

I've added a button to a tableview cell, but I'm having two problems with it:

1) I've invoked a `setTarget:action:` method on the button, but the `action:` method never gets called:

```
[playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playButtonPressed:) 
                 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

2) the cell itself ends up getting selected on the touch, invoking `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, which I don't want to happen.

I've verified that the button is at least seeing the touch by setting its `showsTouchWhenHighlighted` property and seeing it "glow" when pressed. But for whatever reason it looks like the touch event is then getting passed up to its cell superview instead of being handled by the button itself.

I've tried adding the button directly to the cell's `contentView`, as well as to other cell subviews, with no effect. I've also made sure that the button's superview(s) were all touch-enabled.

Any thoughts?

Howard

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do that, the simplest is to add the button to the cell with IB, set a tag number to the button and when you are in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method updating the cell use something like:

```
UIButton *myButton = (UIButton *)[cellYouAreUpdating viewWithTag:-1969];
```

being -1969 the tag number you previously set in IB and cellYouAreUpdating the cell reference. After that you will have a reference to the button in the cell and you could set the add target with the proper selector.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

My be your button Y axis OR Y axis + height  is Higher than its super View (Super view may be cell or contentview of cell) check the heght of superview

Comment: I don't think that was the issue. I wish I'd provided a bit more code context when I posted the question, because I suspect the problem lay elsewhere. I've since added buttons to uitableview cells with no problem. The above code is identical to what works for me now. The only two additional lines I'm currently using are :  button.frame = CGRectMake(244, 5, 75, 40);
[button setTitle:@"Done!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Answer (score 0):

-->For your first problem,use this code

```
UIButton *imgV1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[imgV1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 53)];
[imgV1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]]; 
[imgV1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"expired.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[imgV1 addTarget:self action:@selector(show_product_details:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

-->For your second problem use this in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath     {
```

[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
}